# Failed to implement androidx lifecycle dependencies

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I'm learning to use Android Studio, when I want to implement the lifecycle dependencies in Gradle, an error message appears after the sync. I don't understand why, but I did everything as indicated in the Android Studio documentation.
Do you have any idea where my mistake is?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gs0nv.jpg)

```
val lifecycle_version = "2.5.1"
        val arch_version = "2.1.0"

// ViewModel
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version")
// ViewModel utilities for Compose
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:$lifecycle_version")
// LiveData
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version")
// Lifecycles only (without ViewModel or LiveData)
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycle_version")

// Saved state module for ViewModel
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:$lifecycle_version")

// Annotation processor
kapt("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version")
// alternately - if using Java8, use the following instead of lifecycle-compiler
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_version")

// optional - helpers for implementing LifecycleOwner in a Service
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:$lifecycle_version")

// optional - ProcessLifecycleOwner provides a lifecycle for the whole application process
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:$lifecycle_version")

// optional - ReactiveStreams support for LiveData
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-reactivestreams-ktx:$lifecycle_version")

// optional - Test helpers for LiveData
testImplementation("androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$arch_version")

// optional - Test helpers for Lifecycle runtime
testImplementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-testing:$lifecycle_version")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace **val** with **def**.
In my case, it is working.